# Convert Image into Sepia (ASP.NET)

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I'm working on some image processing project. I managed to find a way how to convert an original image into grey scale & negative, but still haven't manage to find a way to convert into sepia. Can somebody help me?

Here's are the codes:-

1) GreyScaleConverter.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="GreyScaleConverter.aspx.cs"
Inherits="GreyScaleConverter" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Grey Scale Converter</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <center>
            <h1>
                Image Converter</h1>
            Select Image:<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
            <br />
            <asp:Button ID="btnUpload" runat="server" OnClick="btnUpload_Click" Text="Upload" />
            <br />
            <asp:Button ID="btnGreyScale" runat="server" OnClick="btnGreyScale_Click" Text="Convert To Grey Scale" />
            <asp:Button ID="btnSepia" runat="server" OnClick="btnSepia_Click" Text="Convert To Negative" />
            <br />
            <asp:Image ID="Img" runat="server" Height="400px" Width="500px" />
            <br />
        </center>
    </div>
</form>
```

2) GreyScaleConverter.aspx.cs

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;

public partial class GreyScaleConverter : System.Web.UI.Page
{
private Bitmap _current;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Session["filepath"] != null)
    {
        Img.ImageUrl = Session["filepath"].ToString();
        _current = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromFile(Server.MapPath(Session["filepath"].ToString()));
    }
}

protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
    {
        string filePath = Server.MapPath("Images/" + FileUpload1.FileName);
        FileUpload1.SaveAs(filePath);
        Img.ImageUrl = "Images/" + FileUpload1.FileName;
        Session["filepath"] = "Images/" + FileUpload1.FileName;
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Write("Please Select An Image!");
    }
}

protected void btnGreyScale_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Session["filepath"] != null)
    {
        Bitmap temp = (Bitmap)_current;
        Bitmap bmap = (Bitmap)temp.Clone();
        Color col;
        for (int i = 0; i < bmap.Width; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < bmap.Height; j++)
            {
                col = bmap.GetPixel(i, j);
                byte grey = (byte)(.299 * col.R + .587 * col.G + .114 * col.B);
                bmap.SetPixel(i, j, Color.FromArgb(grey, grey, grey));
            }
        }
        _current = (Bitmap)bmap.Clone();
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int a = rnd.Next();
        _current.Save(Server.MapPath("Images/" + a + ".png"));
        Img.ImageUrl = "Images/" + a + ".png";
    }
}

protected void btnSepia_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Session["filepath"] != null)
    {
        Bitmap temp = (Bitmap)_current;
        Bitmap bmap = (Bitmap)temp.Clone();
        Color col;
        for (int i = 0; i < bmap.Width; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < bmap.Height; j++)
            {
                col = bmap.GetPixel(i, j);
                col = Color.FromArgb(255 - col.R, 255 - col.G, 255 - col.B);
                bmap.SetPixel(i, j, col);
            }
        }
        _current = (Bitmap)bmap.Clone();
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int a = rnd.Next();
        _current.Save(Server.MapPath("Images/" + a + ".png"));
        Img.ImageUrl = "Images/" + a + ".png";
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: I did this a couple of years ago, but I don't have the code in front of me.  I _think_ I applied a sepia-coloured overlay over the entire greyscale image.  If nobody answers your question, I will see if I can find it later for you.

Comment: @JaneS Alright, thanks (Y)

Comment: This link should also do what you need.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4624998/convert-image-to-black-white-or-sepia-in-c-sharp